# xUnit tests for Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, xunit, c#-5.0

I want to write `xUnit` tests for my Unity project.
While I am fairly new to Unity itself, I have experience with `xUnit`, hence this test framework and not another one.

Now I created a new solution in Visual Studio 2019 and created a `xUnit` project.
The test solution is in a folder structure next to my Unity project, like proposed in this thread: [Unit tests are inconclusive when adding xUnit project to Unity project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64718598/unit-tests-are-inconclusive-when-adding-xunit-project-to-unity-project).
I also added the (temporary) Unity project `csproj` file (it seems to be created new whenever Unity builds the project new).

Now when I want to run a `xUnit` test, I get error whenever I run "Unity specific code", such as `UnityEngine.Debug.Log` or `UnityEngine.JsonUtility.FromJson`.
The error message reads the following for example

```
Message: 
    System.Security.SecurityException : ECall methods must be packaged into a system module.
Stack Trace: 
    DebugLogHandler.LogFormat(LogType logType, Object context, String format, Object[] args)
    Logger.Log(LogType logType, Object message)
    Debug.Log(Object message)
    Settings.get_AppSettings() line 25
    SettingsTest.AppSettings_Default_Test() line 25
```

What can I do in order to run my `xUnit` tests in Visual Studio?

Comment: Got the same issue creating unit tests for a Godot project.  

Comment: I ended up with a test project for Unity tests that had no Unity specific functionality and also some ugly `#ifdef`'s. A lot of code with Unity specific methods is untested. Not a happy solution but a workaround for now.